# Has there been any recent breakthrough in text stream clustering algorithm based on similarity?

Tags: text, cluster-analysis, similarity

I need to have a lightweight tool for text stream clustering. Lightweight in the sense that it doesn't have memory so that it can remember the previous text entries. Text stream here means continuous feed of alphanumeric and semi structured sentences/phrases eg: logs of any application. similarity based clustering means that the algorithm should cluster the texts in groups having the pattern similarity. eg: text1 = 'aaababac' and text2 = 'aaaaabac' should be grouped together since only one characters differs between them. And the scenario is : first text1 comes up the algorithm should give it an index. then the text2 comes up now the algorithm employs the same method to give it an index. but the condition is the both indexes should be near to each other and while processing text2 the algorithm has no idea what came up in earlier texts. 
It is sort of pattern similarity based hashing.

Now I cant find anything useful. The best solution that I found was simhash.
http://matpalm.com/resemblance/simhash/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a bit underspecified. If you cannot remember previous entries, how are you going to remember the clusters you have seen?
And in particular, usually things are only considered a cluster once you have seen a significant amount of "similar" items. You cannot do this without having at least some "memory" of what is frequent and what isn't. Therefore, there is no reasonable clustering algorithm that really does not have *any* memory. It might not be memorizing the literal objects, but memorizing summaries is not really that different. Hashing means memorizing at least parts of the previously seen data. But is memorizing a statistically signficiant random part of the data that much of a benefit over remembering it exactly?

Much of the things happening are pretending to be not memorizing things, but in fact they are just memorizing the data differently. But as long as it gets published, it is to be considered a success. Even if it doesn't work in practise.

Comment: Thanks.....actually about the 'clustering' we can put it like this way it can be a hashing algorithm which gets the input text clustered based on the pattern they follow. And about the question of why trying to remember a hash instead of the input text itself, we can have a use: if we can hash the text(not a quantitative) into a sort of index(a quantitative) we can have a dynamically analyzable cluster field from where we can extract the clusters of texts as we will i.e, smaller clusters with high similarity or a larger cluster with low similarity among the cluster members.

Comment: Computing distances on hash values usually does not work out very well. Hashes are designed to preserve identity, not similarity; while nearby values are "scrambled" to very different locations to spread them evenly on the output range. (LSH approximates the distance first, making objects identical; then even collides them even more via a small hash value range. It does not compute distances on the hash keys, but considers identical keys candidates!)

Comment: Can the words be keys candidates? But still, as we have only one pass available and we are here dealing with an intelligent agent(agent refers to the algorithm) rather than a expert agent, for our case all the words can be candidates. Please note by expert it means a learning and optimizing type of agent whereas our case i.e, intelligent agent can't have a learning phase. Can this be helpful.

Comment: "One pass" is a wide term, and a lot of cheating is done on that. Technically, you could memorize the data in one pass. Then do all the computations in multiple passes over your memory.
Not remembering even summaries means that you cannot have a result that consists of more than the current observation. Otherwise, you need to remember *something* on the previous data.
So the term "one pass" is worthless without denoting the actual memory constraints.

Comment: Can there be a solution by overlooking the memory-less constraint but considering some finite(i guess very little amount in the level of few 100 MB) memory as available? And not forgetting that the stream is infinite i.e, continuously endless. Actually what I'm trying to do is process real time logs of mixed systems collected at a common gateway. The term 'Logs' may lead to the concept of some structure but we can't assume that since the sources are random and of diverse types and moreover its application should be preferably beyond logs.

Comment: The common approach is of course to define what the algorithm *can* remember. For example, `k` cluster centers. Or the last 100 records. Or a hash code of the last 100. But that is essential to your question what your algorithm is allowed to keep in memory.

Comment: I can keep the history logs or hash values. But I don't think it matters if I keep even the entire history in the memory, since I can't expect the inputs to follow any trends i.e, it can resemble the logs from the history but I can't take it as a useful knowledge since I can't be sure, like "ok, the logs are dependent/resemble the last [some number/amount] of logs encountered". I expect the logs to change abruptly and randomly. I am trying a random idea may be I can implement it by tomorrow. May be we can discuss in that idea tomorrow. And thank you for your interest in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you described is called [incremental clustering](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~itamar/Papers/ITNG2010.pdf) or [data stream clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_stream_clustering).

Comment: Actually I misled you by mentioning clustering. It should be in fact only a hashing/indexing algorithm. I need more of a continuous scaled index/hash which also represents pattern similarity between the texts. The references you gave would be a solution if the problem were to be only of clustering. But it isn't it can be regarded as a dimensionality reduction where the input is a variable length text but the output is a continuous scaled index.